# How to measure the Tablet's touch response time?

Tags: android, ios, touch

Are there available software/hardware tools we can use to measure the the touch response time of a tablet's screen?
I am trying to compare the different touch response time of different manufacturers tablet. 
So far, I found the touchscreen performance test by MOTO Development Group but the test do not have the testing for touch response. Any hints is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from the software side without getting into some GSEvents, and those are private...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could measure the end-to-end (touch sensor->CPU->display) latency by pointing a high-speed camera at it, and counting frames between when your finger makes contact and when the UI responds.